# ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to a Dense layer should be defined. Found None

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, embedding

I'm playing around a bit with Tensorflow 2.7.0 and its new `TextVectorization` layer. However, something does not work quite right in this simple example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

X = np.array(['this is a test', 'a nice test', 'best test this is'])

vectorize_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization()
vectorize_layer.adapt(X)
emb_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=vectorize_layer.vocabulary_size()+1, output_dim=2, input_length=4)
flatten_layer = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(vectorize_layer)
model.add(emb_layer)
model.add(flatten_layer)
#model.add(dense_layer)

model(X)
```

This works so far. I make ints out of words, embed them, flatten them. But if I want to add a `Dense` layer after flattening (i.e. uncomment a line), things break, and I get the error message from the question title. I even used the `input_length` parameter of the `Embedding` layer because the documentation says that I should specify this when using embedding->flatten->dense. But it just does not work.

Do you know how I can get it to work using `Flatten` and not something like `GlobalAveragePooling1D`?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a max length for the sequences.

```
vectorize_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(output_mode = 'int',
                                                    output_sequence_length=10)
```

If you check `model.summary()`, output shape of the `TextVectorization` will be `(None, None)`.

First `None` indicates that model can accept any batch size, and the second one indicates that any sentence that is passed to `TextVectorization` will not be truncated or padded. So the output sentence can have variable length.

Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

X = np.array(['this is a test', 'a nice test', 'best test this is'])

vectorize_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(output_mode = 'int')
vectorize_layer.adapt(X)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(vectorize_layer)

model(np.array(['this is a test']))
>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 4), dtype=int64, numpy=array([[3, 4, 5, 2]])>

model(np.array(['this is a longer test sentence']))
>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 6), dtype=int64, numpy=array([[3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1]])>
```

Redefining it:

```
vectorize_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(output_mode = 'int',
                                                    output_sequence_length = 5)

model(np.array(['this is a longer test sentence']))
>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 5), dtype=int64, numpy=array([[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]])>

model(np.array(['this is']))
>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 5), dtype=int64, numpy=array([[3, 4, 0, 0, 0]])>
```

Defining `output_sequence_length` to a number will make sure the outputs' lengths are a fixed number.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot, that did the trick. Also, good point with just checking the model summary, this will probably save me some trouble on other occasions. Happy new year to you! :)

Comment: Yes, model summary will you give insights what might be wrong. Happy new year! :)